# Querying date in ISO format issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I have date of birth field in my collection which saves data in ISO format like this :-

```
ISODate("1980-01-01T20:20:19.198Z")
```

In my html page the date time picker it gives me date in model like this :-

```
01/01/1980
```

When i query for date of birth it gives me nothing so i tried :-

```
dateofbirth = new Date(req.params.sdob);
dateofbirthFormatted = dateofbirth.toISOString();
```

Still Doesn't give any result. What is correct solution for this issue?

Comment: Query using your `dateofbirth` variable (which is a `Date`), but be mindful of timezone issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need your "date string" in "yyyy-mm-dd" in order to get the same ISO date as you intend, so there is a start. If your "timepicker" cannot produce in this way then manipulate the data in your controller. Presuming "dd/mm/yyyy":

```
var start_date = new Date(string.split("/").reverse().join("-"));
```

Also since your "date of birth" is more of a "timestamp" value and will not *exactly* match that date, then just convert to a date range with a start and end and use "range" operators:

```
// Adding one day in date math or other method
var start_date = new Date(string.split("/").reverse().join("-"))
    end_date = new Date( start_date.valueOf() + ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) );

db.collection.find({ "birthday": { "$gte": start_date, "$lt": end_date } })
```

Essentially looking for all values in "birthday" that could possibly range from "1980-01-01:00:00:00.000Z" and "1980-01-01:23:59:59.999Z"

Answer (score 0):

format manually your input date as yyyy-mm-dd then search

or

simply use momentjs to formate the date this is the link [moment js](http://momentjs.com/)